# C++11 smart pointers use cases

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Let's suppose I'm developing a small movie database. In dynamic language like python I'd write:

```
db = ConnectionFactory.get_connection(db_name) # (1) Create database connection
model = MovieModel(db)                         # (2) object-to-relational mapper
star_wars = Movie("Star Wars", ...)
model.store(star_wars)                         # (3) Save object
et = model.fetch("E.T.")                       # (4) Retrieve one object
movies = model.fetch_all()                     # (5) Retrieve all objects
```

When translating this to C++, problem arises how to pass objects around: by value, by reference, by plain-old-pointers, or by one of a few smart pointers.

Line 1 incorporates an Abstract Factory, which returns subclass of some base class, so returning a pointer is necessary here. Question is, what kind of pointer should be returned? `std::unique_ptr` seems a good fit.

In line 2 `MovieModel` is constructed, which takes a database connection as argument and stores it for future use. As one connection could be shared between one or more Models, database connection should be passed and stored as `std::shared_ptr`, I presume. But then, should I convert `std::unique_ptr` created by `ConnectionFactory` to `shared_ptr` or modify `ConnectionFactory` to return `shared_ptr`?

In line 3, an object being stored in database. As `Movie` is simple "data" class, it should be passed by value, or better, by const reference. That's simple, but in line 4 another object is retrieved. Since `Movie` has "value" semantics, returning by value seems natural. But what happens when particular movie is not found? Is it better to throw an exception, or change return type to smart pointer and return a `nullptr` in that case?

Last, a collection of objects is returned. Is it better to return a container (e.g, `std::vector`) of objects, or container of (smart)pointers. In latter case, which pointers?

Comment: I recommend you don't think of smart pointers as pointers, but think about it as ownership: [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) you use for things that can only have a single owner at a time, while you can use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for things that can have multiple concurrent owners.

Comment: So, if there's a *possibility* that an object have more than one owner, I should use `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Yes that would be a good idea.

Comment: @el.pescado alternatively, see if you can arrange your code so that the object has *one* owner, and a number of users (and where the owner outlives all other users). Then you can use `unique_ptr` which is simpler and easier to reason about. Shared ownership shouldn't be the default

Comment: @jalf I would argue that shared ownership is way simpler than artificially creating some owner that outlives all users. Only if that happens completely naturally in the code, i would consider that method. But in a setting where many different classes do many different things in parallel, it seems way simpler and less error prone to just share ownership instead of trying to guess who lives longest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 1+2: I think it would make sense to already initially return by `shared_ptr`, as a DB connection seems to be inherently "sharable" in this design. That way, Case2 solves itself.

Case 3: Pass `Movie` by const reference. If `Movie` is a value-like class (and doesn't have any expensive-to-copy handle like stuff), a simple single version of `store` with a const-ref parameter should do it and keep the code simple.

If you need to model "not found" in a `fetch` method, use `boost::optional<Movie>` (or something similar) as return value.

Case Last: for `Movie`use a collection by-value (`std::vector<Movie>`). (In C++11 the returned vector will be moved anyway.)

Comment: I agree with these answers. Although I would probably have `fetch_all` take an output iterator instead of returning anything.

Answer (score 2):

> db = ConnectionFactory.get_connection(db_name) # (1) Create database
>   connection

Who owns db? When it is destroyed?

1. This stack owns it and should be destroyed in the end => use `std::unique_ptr`
2. This is saved in a class(eg MovieManager) member and the class will live as long as all other objects => use `std::unique_ptr` and pass raw pointers to other objects
3. db may outlive this stack and the class and is shared with other objects => `std::shared_ptr`

Note in all the above cases, factory should just return a `unique_ptr` unless it returns an existing shared connection which case it is a `shared_ptr`. `unique_ptr` can automatically be upgraded to `shared_ptr`

> model = MovieModel(db)                         # (2)
>   object-to-relational mapper

1. if db was std::unique_ptr and you want MoviewModel to take ownership from now on, `std::move(db)`
2. Model will be destroyed in this stack, pass `db.get()`
3. Model needs shared ownership as any of the models might be destroyed last, pass as shared_ptr

> ```
> star_wars = Movie("Star Wars", ...) 
> model.store(star_wars)    # (3) Save object
> ```

Two options:

1. Make store overloaded for `const Movie&` and `Movie&&`
2. Make store take Movie by value

If you don't want to use star_wars again in this function, call `std::move(star_wars)`

> et = model.fetch("E.T.")                       # (4) Retrieve one
>   object

As object with exception or `optional<Movie>`

> movies = model.fetch_all()                     # (5) Retrieve all
>   objects

`std::vector<Movie>`

Answer (score 1):

edit: I said some not so clever things here, completely ignoring the C++11 in the title.

Some personal opinions on 3 and 5:

3) I can not think of any reason to use value here instead of const reference. At least as long as the storing does not happen in some very unusual way.

Last point: I would always prefer a container of pointers to minimize random copying around of memory. In C++11 you can probably use either unique_ptr or shared_ptr in them, depending on what they are used for later.